# creating nuget package adds project folder name to payload file path

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package

I'm attempting to create a nuget package using Nuget Package Explorer. The project is just a collection of dlls and files I need copied to the output (bin) directory of the project in which it is used, which unless I'm mistaken is pretty much the way nuget packages work.

However, after creating the package the path to the files I want copied appears to be incorrect, even though I specified no such path in my package.

I created the package, added the libs added the two platforms I want to support (Win8.1 and WP8.1 RT) and added the files for each platform in their respective libs container.

When I install the package into my project it creates the package folder with the exact same structure. Everything looks good.

However, when I then build the project, instead of trying to add the contents of for example:

> packages/MyPackage/libs/wpa81/MyProject.WindowsPhone.Data.xml

it's instead attempting to find this:

> packages/MyPackage/libs/wpa81/**MyProject.WindowsPhone**/MyProject.WindowsPhone.Data.xml

and so I get an error like:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(1496,9):
>   error APPX0702: Payload file 'C:\Users\Me\Visual
>   Studio\AnotherProject\packages\MyPackage\lib\wpa81\MyProject.WindowsPhone\MyProject.WindowsPhone.Data.xml'
>   does not exist.

now, MyProject.WindowsPhone IS the name of the original project I used to create the content I want to include in the package, but I make no reference to this folder anywhere in the nuget package or manifest.

If I manually create that folder and move everything inside it works, but none of the other packages I use require me to do this. I want to simply reference the files that are there, where is it getting this folder name from?

does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? please let me know what information I can add to help identify the problem...

Comment: I just noticed after posting this that it does appear to find and copy the dll files as I have no errors and they are properly referenced. it's the non dll files that are missing. I don't want them added as content, they should go into the bin folder... but perhaps I'm doing this part incorrectly?

Comment: Can you post your nuspec?

Comment: it appears this may not be related to nuget after all, but a problem with my solution, so I created a new post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29857826/adding-reference-to-windows-phone-class-library-via-project-will-build-adding-t). if the answer to that resolves this I will update this with that answer, thank you!